# Example of left-tail distribution

Tags: probability, distributions

Assuming that $X>0$, a lognormal distribution for such a random variable is considered right-tailed because it skews towards the right.

Out of curiosity, is there a well-known PDF that is left-tailed, i.e., skews to the left for $X>0$?

Thanks.

Comment: Sure, try a Beta(2,1) distribution for example.

Comment: "Right-tailed" is not a description commonly applied to distributions, because all distributions have two tails.  You might mean something like "long right-tailed."  As far your question goes, for every such $X$ there is a corresponding random variable $Y=-X$ that has exactly the properties you ask of it.  It would be hard to claim the distribution of $Y$ is not "well-known" given that it is obtained in such a trivial way from that of $X.$

Comment: @whuber: does a binomial distribution with $(\alpha, \beta) < 1$ have tails?

Comment: @naught *Every* distribution has tails.  The "right tail" is described by the survival function and the "left tail" by the distribution function, both of which always exist.  I don't know what "$(\alpha,\beta)$" might possibly mean for a Binomial distribution, though.

Comment: Bah, sorry, I meant to type beta distribution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, distributions with tails are defined base on the definitions of the random variable in question. For example, for a random variable $X$ representing the amount of rainfall or revenue or population income. These all take only positive values such that $X \ge 0$ and they tend to follow very right-tailed distributions, such as Log-Normal, Gamma, Weibull and other common distributions.

However there are much fewer examples in common literature for random variables that are left-tailed and take values that skew to the left. There is a wide variety of data that exhibits this property, such as survival of human life (age of mortality) or scores of easy tests or simply flipping a weighted coin. It is generally tricky to parameterise a distribution which has a cutoff $<\infty$ so we don't really see too many formal well-known distributions that satisfy the left-skew. For another random variable, say $Y \ge 0$, as mentioned in the comment above, the Beta , Binomial, Dirichlet and even a Generalised Extreme Value distributions can be left tailed.

[image: Beta with parameters a=5, b=2]

[image: Binomial with parameter p=5/7]

In fact for some random variable $Z \in \Bbb R$ there are negatively-skewed distributions without placing a restriction on the strictly positive conditions used in economics for historical analysis of efficiency and by big banks and financial institutions for expected profits and regulatory requirements (skewed Normal).

[image: Skewed Normal]

Answer (score 0):

If you expand your horizons, you can see that there are several more distributions which can have left tails.  For example, the 4-parameter Stable, BetaPert, Weibull, Triangle, Beta (mentioned above),  and Generalized Extreme Value (GEV).  The GEV distribution shown is also known as the smallest value or minimum value extreme distribution.

[image]